# Sublime tmPreference file: How to have multiple scopes?

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to modify a sublime text textmate-style `tmPreference` file to have an additional setting. Initially the file has symbol list setting that applies just to the scope of headlines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Symbol List</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.orgmode orgmode.headline</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>showInSymbolList</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But I want to add in a *comment mechanism that applies to any line* in the file:

```
 <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.orgmode</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>; </string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

Is there a way to handle multiple scopes within a single `tmPreferences` file?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to have make two .tmPreference files instead. Sublime Text will scan your plugin's folder for the multiple tmPreference files.